# Setting up a command line alarm clock in Gnome

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I'd love to have a CLI alarm clock and came up with this:
 `echo 'gnome-open /home/me/alarm.ogg' | at 09:15`

Any ideas why above doesn't work, or anything along those lines?

---

## I've found an answer:

```
echo 'cvlc /home/user/alarm.wav' | at 08:47
```

This works perfectly (by using the command line mode of VLC)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See edited section of the question: This works absolutely fine (with terminal closed etc):

```
echo 'cvlc /home/user/alarm.ogg' | at 08:49
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't work because `gnome-open` targets usually require a `$DISPLAY`. It also won't work for other such uses since stdout is redirected to mail by `at`.

The [alarm-clock-applet](http://alarm-clock.pseudoberries.com/) for Gnome is available in the Ubuntu repositories and elsewhere.

Comment: is that specific for 'at ...' (because on its own it works fine! 'gnome-open example.wav')?

Comment: @ajo: Yes, when you run something using `at`, there's no `$DISPLAY`. When you run it directly from a shell prompt there is.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add the ability to show a notification message.

```
echo "DISPLAY=:0;notify-send 'an alarm message';cvlc ~/Music/tones/alarm-905.wav;" | at 11:42
```

Also this will play the alarm in a loop with `cvlc` if you not sure how to stop it.

```
pkill vlc
```